# Power BI: Line chart with special data

Tags: powerbi

My data is an xlsx file and it looks like the following:
[image]

The value of A at Day1 is 5; the value of C at Day4 is 2 and so on.

I'd like to create a line chart in Power BI and my requirements are the following:

1. Use 4 lines in one single line chart to show the trends for A, B, C and D.
2. I can use a filter to show or hide any line.

The following image is what I need:
[image]

If I transpose my data like the following, it's easy to create the line chart but I couldn't filter out the line. For example, I cannot hide A and C just like the above image.
[image]

How can I create a line chart with my two requirements?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Table design is wrong. Should be (Day, Group, Value)
Then it's easy.

Comment: Hello @Pieter, do you mean the table should have three columns: Day, Name and Value? Can you use the example table in my question to illustrate how to create the table?

| Day    | Name | Value |
| Day1  |   A      |    5     |
| Day2  |   A      |    1     |
| Day3  |   A      |    8     |
| Day4  |   A      |    7     |
| Day5  |   A      |    6     |

How can you put B, C and D in this table?

Comment: What do "A", "B", "C" represent or describe? Whatever that represents (column name).

Comment: Let's say A, B, C and D represent countries. The value is temperature. 

| Day    | Country | Temperature |
| ------ | --------- | -------------- |
| Day1  |   A         |    5                 |

| Day2  |   A         |    1                 |
| Day3  |   A         |    8                 |
| Day4  |   A         |    7                 |
| Day5  |   A         |    6                 |

How can you put B, C and D in this table?

Comment: Oh, okay. If you used a line graph, Country would be a series. (so one line per series/Country).

Comment: Yes, one line is for one country. I'd like to create a line chart which shows the temperature trend for four different countries. Do you know how to do this in Power BI?

Comment: Okay, Line Chart. X-Axis:Day, Y-Axis: Temp, Series: Country
You'd likely need a measure for your Temperature. like MIN('Data'[temperature]) for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254478/discussion-between-pieter-and-sheng).